# .htaccess silent redirection to subfolder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect silently all requests of a domain to a subfolder if the folder / file doesn't exist.

Unfortunately some scenarios doesn't work or work non-silently.

1. works: http://mydomain.com/index.html -- it shows the content of production/index.html
2. does not work: http://mydomain.com/ -- it doesn't show production/index.html
3. works: http://mydomain.com/test/ -- it shows the content of production/test/index.html
4. does not work: http://mydomain.com/test -- it redirects the url (instead of a silent redirection) to http://mydomain.com/production/test/ and shows the content of production/test/index.html

Below is the .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/production/

# Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all those to insert /production folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /production/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `mod_dir` is appending a trailing slash after `mod_rewrite` execution. Change your rules to this to overcome this issue:

```
DirectorySlash Off 
Options -Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 

# add a trailing slash for directories 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]*?[^/])[?\s] 
RewriteRule [^/]$ /%1/ [L,R=302,NE] 

# take care of landing page: 
RewriteRule ^/?$ production/ [L] 

# Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Rewrite all those to insert /production folder 
RewriteRule ^((?!production).+)$ production/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this didn't help. Point #2 and #4 above still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, same thing, except now #1 doesn't work either.

Comment: Unfortunately we are back to where we started, point #2 and #4 still doesn't work. (#1 works again)

Comment: This is fully tested solution. Test it out in a different browser to avoid 301 caching.

Comment: Also `http://mydomain.com/` will show `http://mydomain.com/index.html` if that exists instead `http://mydomain.com/production/index.html`. That is because of your conditions that only files/directories that don't exist should be sent to `/production`. Let me know if you want an exception here.

Comment: Yes, I know about our condition checking for existing files and folders, this is why http://mydomain.com/index.html does not exist. The new code now handles #2 right, only #4 doesn't work now.

Comment: No you're mistaken. #4 already worked with previous version. You're still testing in old browser. Either clear your browser cache or test in a new browser.

Comment: Sorry, but no, #4 never worked. I have cleared the cache and also tried it in a new browser and #4 still doesn't work. Keep in mind when I'm saying it doesn't work I mean the redirection is not silent, but http://mydomain.com/test turns to http://mydomain.com/production/test in the browser. But if "http://mydomain.com/test/" is used instead of "http://mydomain.com/test" then it works as expected - silently redirects. The difference is the ending "/"

Comment: With the `DirectorySlash Off` line at top of my suggested code `mod_dir` cannot add a trailing slash hence you will not see an external redirect to `mydomain.com/production/test`.

Comment: Strange it is still there, I mean #4 really doesn't work. I use DirectorySlash Off, exactly as you suggested, cache cleared and different (new) browsers tested from multiple computers.

Comment: I have just updated rules one more time. See updated code for `R=301` rule.

Comment: Yes, thanks, unfortunately even with that change (R=301) scenario #4 still doesn't work.

Comment: Done, now I get "Forbidden, you don't have access /production/test on this server" when calling mydomain.com/test without the trailing "/" (scenario #4)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57873/discussion-between-anubhava-and-zoltan-fedor).